# Fill columns with data from other sheet based on content from another column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Using Google Sheets, I'm trying to do something specific that is apparently un-searchable (zero results).

Sheet 1 contains data in column A. I want to import the data in Columns A and B to their respective columns on Sheet 2, but *only* if that same row *also* has (literally any) data in Column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this in Sheet2!A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Sheet1!C:C), Sheet1!A:B, ))
```

or perhaps this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C:C), Sheet1!A:B, ))
```